# Storing Search results for Future Use

Tags: sql

I have the following scenario where the search returns a list of userid  values (1,2,3,4,5,6... etc.) If the search were to be run again, the results are guaranteed to change given some time. However I need to stored the instance of the search results to be used in the future.

We have a current implementation (legacy), which creates a record for the search_id with the  criteria and inserts every row returned into a different table with the associated search_id.

```
table search_results
   search_id unsigned int FK, PK (clustered index)
   user_id unsigned int FK
```

This is an unacceptable approach as this table has grown onto millions of records. I've considered partitioning the table, but either I will have numerous partitions (1000s).

I've optimized the existing tables that search results expired unless they're used elsewhere, so all the search results are referenced elsewhere.

In the current schema, I cannot store the results as serialized arrays or XML. I am looking to efficiently store the search result information, such that it can be efficiently accessed later without being burdened by the number of records.

EDIT: Thank you for the answers, I don't have any problems running the searches themselves, but the result set for the search gets used in this case for recipient lists, which will be used over and over again, the purpose of storing is exactly to have a snapshot of the data at the given time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **don't store query results**. It's a terrible idea!

- It introduces [statefulness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_%28computer_science%29), which is very bad unless you *really* (**really really**) need it
- It isn't [scalable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) (as you're finding out)
- The data is stale as soon as it's stored

The correct approach is to fix your query/database so it runs acceptable quickly.

If you can't make the queries faster using better SQL and/or indexes etc, I recommend using  [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org) (or any text-based search engine) and denormalizing your database into it. Lucene queries are incredibly fast.

I recently did exactly this on a large web site that was doing what you're doing: It was caching query results from the production relational database in the session object in an attempt top speed up queries, but it was a mess, and wasn't much faster anyway - before my time, a "senior" java developer (whose name started with Jam.. and ended with .illiams) who was actually a moron decided it was a good idea.

I put in Solr (a java-tailored lucene implementation) and kept Solr up to date with the relational database (using work queues) and the web queries are now just a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you need to store every search? Surely you would want the most up to date information available for the user ?

I'll admit first, this isn't a great solution.

- Setup another database alongside your current one [SYS_Searches]
- The save script could use SELECT INTO [SYS_Searches].Results_{Search_ID}
- The script that retrieves can do a simple SELECT out of the matching table.

**Benefits:**

- Every search is neatly packed into it's own table, [preferably in another DB]
- The retrieval query is very simple
- The retrieval time should be very quick, no massive table scans.

**Drawbacks:**

- You will have a table for every x user * y searches a user can store.

This could get very silly very quickly unless there is management involved to expire results or the user can only have 1 cached search result set.

Not pretty, but I can't think of another way.